# Is it able to add version for Windows Runtime Component(C++/WinRT)?

Tags: windows-runtime, cppwinrt

I am developing a Windows Runtime Component with C++/WinRT.

I want to know if it is possible to add version information for the component?

For example, if we want to add version information to legacy dll file, we just add a .rc file into the project and the dll file will contain the version information.

How should I do this for a Windows Runtime Component?

Comment: Does “add version information to the windows runtime componnet(c++/winrt)” mean that you want to see the version information in the properties when you right-click the dll file?

Comment: With [reg-free WinRT](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/04/30/enhancing-non-packaged-desktop-apps-using-windows-runtime-components/) (introduced in Windows 10 1903) I believe you can supply a `version` property for the `assemblyIdentity` key in your [application manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests). This allows you to activate a particular version of any given runtime class. I don't know whether that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Yes, I want to add some information into the dll file and then I can see it in file's property.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you, this may be what I want. Another question is, if it is not a reg-free WinRT, how can I add version info?

Comment: I am developing a Windows Runtime Component to wrap Windows.Devices.Gpio functions for my customer to access I/Os easier. However, I think it would be better to include version info in winmd or dll file from file management viewpoint.

Comment: I tried to add a .rc file into windows runtime component(c++/winrt) and built it, then I could see the information in dll's property. If you try this, is it what you want?

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT Thank you for your information, I will try it and update the result.

Comment: @Faywang-MSFT, sorry for the late reply. I just tried to add rc file and the version info can be seen in my dll file. Thank you so much! Besides, is it possible to add this kind of info to `winmd` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > If it is possible to add version information for the component

You can Right-Click the component project -> Add -> Resource, then you can add Verion information in your project. After building it, you can see the version information in the dll's property in File Explorer.

In addition, each type in a windows runtime file can be associated with a version. You can check the [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.VersionAttribute?view=winrt-19041) attribute.

Note that, this is not the same as the DLL version information you see in File Explorer. The winmd files are not DLLs, so you can not do the same to add this kind of info to winmd file.